# How can I select pricing from a table grouped by a product and packaging type, but get the most recent one PRIORITIZING by company_id assigned?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a prices table. The columns are:

```
product_id  int 
company_id  int NULL    
amount  int 
packaging_type  enum('Drum','Pail','Tote','Bulk','Jug') 
effective_at    date
```

There are prices assigned for product_id's that have several different types of packaging. General pricing has a company_id that is 0. So I can GROUP BY packaging_type and product_id, select the MAX(effective_date) and get the most recent pricing for each product with each packaging type.

I offer all companies a base pricing, which I represent with a company_id that is 0. But some companies I want to offer special pricing for. So I want to assign the foreign company_id a value related to my companies table, and if one of these values exist I want it to get selected based on product and packaging type, rather than the company_id that is 0.

So my SELECT statement will select all company_id = 0 most current effective_at rows for each product group, but if a value exists for a specified company_id then I want to select that row instead no matter the effective_at date. There should only ever be one price per product/packaging type per company.

[image: My Table]

I'm writing this in Laravel Eloquent. The command so far looks like this:

```
$sub = Price::select(
        'product_id',
        'packaging_type',
        DB::raw('MAX(effective_at) as current_at'),
        DB::raw('MAX(company_id) as company')
    )
    ->where('company_id', 0)
    ->groupBy('product_id', 'packaging_type');

$generalPricing = Price::join(
        DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) current_prices"),
        function($join) {
            $join->on('current_prices.product_id', '=', 'prices.product_id')
                ->on('current_prices.packaging_type', '=', 'prices.packaging_type')
                ->on('current_prices.current_at', '=', 'prices.effective_at');
        }
    )
    ->addBinding($sub->getBindings(), 'join')
    ->get();
```

That translates to this SQL:

```sql
select *
from `prices`
inner join (
    select
        `product_id`,
        `packaging_type`,
        MAX(effective_at) as current_at,
        MAX(company_id) as company
    from `prices`
    where `company_id` in (?, ?)
    group by `product_id`, `packaging_type`
) current_prices
    on `current_prices`.`product_id` = `prices`.`product_id`
    and `current_prices`.`packaging_type` = `prices`.`packaging_type`
    and `current_prices`.`current_at` = `prices`.`effective_at`
```

I think I need to first select out the company specific pricing, then join it to the general most recent pricing, but I'm not sure how to do that and have it select all unique packaging/product groupings with specified company pricing getting selected over general pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove that `WHERE company_id = 0` and use an `ORDER BY` clause to show which values get shown first?

Also, instead of using `->toSql()` and `addBindings()` you can just pass in the query builder to the `joinSub()` method.

```php
$sub = Price::query()
    ->select(
        'product_id',
        'packaging_type',
        DB::raw('MAX(effective_at) AS current_at'),
        DB::raw('MAX(company_id) AS company'),
    )
    ->groupBy('product_id', 'packaging_type')
    ->orderByRaw('company_id DESC, effective_at DESC');

$generalPricing = Price::query()
    ->joinSub($sub, 'current_prices', function($join) {
        $join->on('current_prices.product_id', '=', 'prices.product_id')
            ->on('current_prices.packaging_type', '=', 'prices.packaging_type')
            ->on('current_prices.current_at', '=', 'prices.effective_at');
    })
    ->get();
```